# Replacing a vertical side nav bar with another one in AppMobi (jQMobi - Intel XDK)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, appmobi, jqmobi

I'm developing a web application with AppMobi (a library based on jQMobi and not jQMobile) with two sidebars. Each sidebar shows when I click on the respectful button.

Buttons code:

```
<a id='button1' href="javascript:;" onclick='showMenu1()' class='icon folder' style='float:left' >Menu 1</a>
    <script>
    function showMenu1() {
            $("#menu2").html("#menu1");
    }
</script>

<a id='button2' href="javascript:;" onclick='showMenu2()' class='icon folder' style='float:left' >Menu 2</a>
    <script>
    function showMenu2() {
            $("#menu1").html("#menu2");
    }
</script>
```

Side navigation bars code:

```
<nav id="menu1" >
    <div class="icon star" >Node 1</div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >Sub-node 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Sub-node 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  >Sub-node 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="menu2" >
    <div class="icon star" >Node 1</div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >Sub-node 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Sub-node 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  >Sub-node 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The clicks work but not the "html" function. What is the problem ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

HTML / button 1 / menu 2

```
<a id='button1' href="#" class='icon folder' style='float:left' >Menu 1</a>
```

Code

```
$('a#button1').on('click', function () {
 $("#menu2").html("#menu1");
});
```

HTML / button 2 / menu 1

```
<a id='button2' href="#" class='icon folder' style='float:left' >Menu 1</a>
```

Code

```
$('a#button2').on('click', function () {
 $("#menu1").html("#menu2");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function "on" is not integrated in jQMobi, which is a light version of jQMobile (or jQuery Mobile which is also lighter than the original jQuery library). Consequently, the code does not work.

Comment: Well the click works with my code, the problem is in the html function.

Comment: @MHDaouas check this example i created for you. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/22Ta9/

Comment: This is based on jQuery Mobile while I'm working on jQuery Mobi (jQMobi), a lightweight jQuery Mobile for web apps development. Your code does not work.

Comment: First, it's not appMobi - appMobi was the company that developed jqMobi.  Now it's App Framework :)

Second - $().on is implemented .  If it's not, you are running a version over a year old.

Also, use $.ui.updateSideMenu to update the menu contents - http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api/index.html#$.ui.updateSideMenu

Answer (score 0):

have you try this?

```
$('a#button1').bind('click',function () {

  //your functions

});
```